# Illegal polymorphic or qualified type in typeclass

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

The following file `Poly.hs` file

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module Poly () where

type ListModifier s = forall a. s -> [a] -> [a]

instance Monoid (ListModifier s) where
  mempty = const id
  mappend f g st = f st . g st
```

Gets the typechecker to complain:

```
Poly.hs:8:10: Illegal polymorphic or qualified type: ListModifier s …
    In the instance declaration for ‘Monoid (ListModifier s)’
Compilation failed.
```

Initially I though it couldn't compose the rank 2 types but:

```
λ> :t (undefined :: forall a . a -> String ) . (undefined :: forall b . String -> b)
(undefined :: forall a . a -> String ) . (undefined :: forall b . String -> b)
  :: String -> String
```

I feel the `Poly` module is in some way inherently inconsistent but I can't put my finger on the problem.

Comment: The second example doesn't involve any rank 2 types. It is the same as `:t (undefined :: a -> String ) . (undefined :: String -> b)`. It just has the `forall` written explicitly instead of implicitly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ListModifier` is a type alias, not a “real” type. Type aliases are essentially macros at the type level, always expanded by the typechecker before actually typechecking. That means your instance declaration is equivalent to the following:

```
instance Monoid (forall a. s -> [a] -> [a]) where
```

Even if that *were* allowed, it would overlap with the existing `Monoid (a -> b)` instance, so it still wouldn’t work. The larger problem, however, is that you can’t have an instance defined on a `forall`-quantified type because it wouldn’t make sense from the perspective of instance resolution.

What you could do instead is define a fresh type instead of a type alias using `newtype`:

```
newtype ListModifier s = ListModifier (forall a. s -> [a] -> [a])
```

Now you can define a `Monoid` instance, since typeclass resolution only needs to look for the `ListModifier` type, which is much simpler to match on:

```
instance Monoid (ListModifier s) where
  mempty = ListModifier (const id)
  mappend (ListModifier f) (ListModifier g) = ListModifier (\st -> f st . g st)
```

Alternatively, you could keep your type alias and define a newtype with a different name, like `ReifiedListModifier`, then define an instance on that, and you could only do the wrapping when you need to store a `ListModifier` in a container or use a typeclass instance.